# return Laravel Pagiation array item

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, paginator

I am collecting data from angular with below method.

```
$result = RepairCategory::select('id','Name')->paginate(10);
```

the result will be like this

[image]

I want to process the data array with some conditions. When I try to store the data in another variable.

```
$items = $result->data;
```

Its returning error like

> Undefined property: Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator::$data

I tried also

```
$items = $result['data'];
```

and

```
$items = $result[0]->data;
```

Please suggest a good method to get this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access elements by DB column names such as `id` and `Name`. and

You should write foreach loop to store all records in a array,

```
$res = [];
foreach($result as $row){
$res[] = ['id'=>$row->id , 'Name' => $row->Name];
}
```

OR

You can directly convert object to array by [**`toArray()`**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-serialization#serializing-to-arrays) method.

Reference links:-

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/pagination

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-serialization#serializing-to-arrays

Answer (score 1):

To get an array of model arrays (not sure if this is a proper solution):

```
collect(YourModel::all()->paginate(20)->items())->toArray();
```

To get an array of model objects simply do:

```
YourModel::all()->paginate(20)->items();
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate your result like this.

```
foreach($result as $key => $value){
  echo $value->id;
  echo $value->name;
}
```